# storing received array from OAuth in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm receiving the following array from google login OAuth and trying to store the received data.

```
["given_name"]=> string(8) "Abdallah" ["family_name"]=> string(5) "Sakre"
```

The following `getName()` will work if I'm storing the full name, but i want to store the given_name and family_name separately.

```
$user = User::firstOrCreate(
                ['email' => $socialUser->getEmail()],
                ['first_name' => $socialUser->getName()]
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@abdallah Sakre did you try doing

```php
$socialUser['given_name']
```

I have done it like this and it works!